# How to make Android Studio Faster ? Critical Case

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, build, android-gradle-plugin

My Android studio is taking 1hour+ to build the gradle. 
Can anyone suggest me how to make it faster? I can't deploy any app. Its working perfectly fine after build. I have a HP 2000-329WM Laptop with 3GB RAM. Can anyone suggest the best method to make the Android Studio to work perfectly fine like in Macbook. I am using a physical device and hence emulator and other optional features can be removed. 
Suggest me the best way to OPTIMIZE Android Studio Performance without adding new Hardware resources(RAM.etc)
Android Studio Version : 2.1.2
OS : Windows 10
RAM : 3GB

Comment: I'm using 8gb ram 256gb SSD HDD i7 CPU, I change the normal HDD to SSD now performance is very good

Comment: Try increase Android Studio memory like this http://lifeofcoding.com/2015/01/19/How-to-increase-Android-studio-memory-limit-in-Mac/

Comment: @IvanBarayev can you recommend him a good site to download ram? :)

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I too felt the same when i had used Mac with SSD. But currently, I can't afford high expenses. That's why i am seeking for a Software Patch.

Comment: @Razgriz you catch it from good place :) I missed the "without" word, I think I have to go sleep :)

Comment: @DanhDC Thanks DanhDC. It sounds good. Lemme check it out

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a hack but I think the best way is to switch to Linux. Windows 10 consumes more RAM than any other operating system.

Also if possible add some RAM to your Laptop it helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

When you have created the project, to go Files>Settings>Build, Execution, Deployment and then check the Offline Gradle.

Once you are done making the project uncheck offline Gradle and then run.
This will speed up your project.